# Connecting a LightScribe drive to a VM via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, lightscribe

I'm looking for a way to connect a LightScribe DVD drive (LG GH22LS30 specifically) in an USB enclosure, attached to a physical host, to a virtual machine running on a Hyper-V server. My goal is to enable users using a shared VM with LightScribe System Software and a CD label making software, and being able to just plug the LightScribe drive to their workstation or laptop, login to the VM via Remote Desktop and burn a LightScribe disk while avoiding any local software installs etc.

System setup:

- Workstations are running Windows 7 Enterprise x64.
- Server is running Windows Server 2012 with Hyper-V.
- The VM is running Windows 7 Enterprise, LightScribe System Software, and Acoustica CD Label Maker.

Currently, the LightScribe drive can be seen in the VM as an ordinary disk drive. Even plug&play works well over Remote Desktop. However, the problem is the LightScribe software won't see the LightScribe device.

My question is whether this is even possible, and if yes, how to configure it to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it *doesnt* work, is that the virtual machine is using a generic virtual CD/DVD ROM driver.  The actual hardware is abstracted from the VM and all it *knows* is that there is a CD/DVD ROM device is present.  The reality is, there might not actually be hardware there.  It could just be an .ISO or even another virtual drive.

Does this mean it cant work?  Not necessarily.  If you can do USB passthrough, you might be able to install the LightScribe software on the VM and it *could* work.

See these directions for [Adding USB Support to Hyper-V with Help of USB Redirector](http://www.incentivespro.com/hyper-v-usb.html).  This might be what you are looking for.